# Does Anyone Really Know The Time? (ha!)

Tags: ios, iphone, time, utc

Can an iOS app access the time of events using the iOS clock?

This would seem to be a simple question… but couldn’t find anything on Google search or here on Stackoverflow either.

Q1. I’m doing a feasibility study on building an app that needs to record the precise moment an event occurs. For example, if an event in astronomy, nature (e.g. lightning) occurs at 16h18m22s (4:18pm, 22 seconds), and the app supports the user to record when the event occurs, can the exact time the user taps the button be recorded using the iOS clock as a time reference?

Q2. How much precision is offered by the iOS clock? Is it possible to record the event-time as a decimal of one second? Milliseconds?
For example: 16h18m22s50c (where the last two digits represent 50 centiseconds or 0.5 of a second).

Q3. Would it be safe to assume that, apart from timezone differences, that everyone’s iOS device is reading exactly the same time, what one might call "universal device time"?

Q4. Or if this approach using the iOS clock seems a bit clunky, especially where ultra accuracy is required, would it be smarter to get a feed from an atomic clock server?

Thanks for any input on this one. Appreciated!
Cheers

Comment: The user can change the time on their device

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because most of the questions are trivial to answer with a couple of seconds of searching or thinking.

Answer (score 1):

Q1: yes! Using `[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]` you get [*sub-millisecond precision*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/tdef/c:@T@NSTimeInterval)

Q2: you are going to get milliseconds as explained in Q1.

Q3: Since `timeIntervalSince1970` gives you exactly what it says (the time interval since 1970), yes - that is a property unaffected of timezones. (watch out for the **but** below)

Q4: using a server will destroy any way of retrieving an accurate result since you have to contact the server and wait for a response, that will take around 100ms which is far worse than every inaccuracy the device clock would have.

## BUT

the user can change its device time which makes the measurement still exact but useless since it no longer reflect the actual time! What you can do in this case is

1. retrieve the current timestamp of the action on the device
2. contact a server with a properly set up clock
3. compare the measurement and ignore the measurement if it is too far off / alert the user to correct his system time. A comparison threshold of half a second should be okay unless your server is very far away or very slow.

Comment: Thanks luk2302 - that answer is appreciated. Getting this working will not be that trivial. Especially considering we have to absolutely sure everyone has the same time.